# Android activity for canvas keeps crashing

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas

As soon as I start the activity, the phone hangs and then crashes. Logcat does not show why it crashes.

I have a canvas where circles keep appearing from top of the screen one after another and move down in a line at a constant rate . Here is my code for onDraw:

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
     int dy = 1;
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    for (int i=0, j=0; i<= dy/55; i=i++, j=j+55){
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2, dy+j, 25, paint); // there is a horizontal distance of 5 between 2 circles
    }
        dy +=2;

    invalidate();       
}
```

I think it is too much to process. Do i need to do it in a different thread.

Comment: Is your onDraw method in a custom View? If yes, try just to remove invalidate();

Comment: Your `onDraw()` method isn't really doing anything, other than immediately calling itself. The `paint` calls can/should be moved outside of this method. Each time through, you set `dy = 1`, so the `dy +=2` line does nothing. And, in the `for` loop, `dy/55` will evaluate to 0, so the loop never runs.

Comment: Yes, it is. I tried removing invalidate(). Still the same thing. But if invalidate() is not present I will not have any motion on my canvas.

Comment: Also, you might make sure `paint` isn't null.

Comment: ohh that int dy = 1; is not in onDraw. It is initialized in the main class globally. Every time onDraw invalidates dy is incremented by 2.

Comment: Try to look on this class for canvas animation: https://github.com/nfirex/CanvasAnimationView/tree/master/src/com/wagado/widget . It is eclipse project with samples that use custom(non android) animation. onDraw-method is intended only to show the current status, and you can't animate something in it.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem why it's crashing:
You are calling `invalidate()` within `onDraw()` method. When you call `invalidate()`, it will call `onDraw()` method. So when you call `invalidate()` within `onDraw()` method, you have ended up creating an INFINITE loop that never ends.

So how to accomplish what you are trying to do? Yes you need to run this in a separate thread. Use `Handlers` and within that increment your `dy` value and then call `invalidate()` there. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7787796/4747587

Comment: Still the same thing. I even tried increasing the time(ms) in postDelayed but same thing happens. I am going to try with surfaceView and if that doesn't work then I'll have to use a different approach to achieve this.

Comment: I think you are blocking the UIThread. Post your code after using the `handlers`, I will take a look.