# AlertDialog with TextView - can't use textView.setText method

Tags: android

I'm trying to draw a parabola with delay, using custom view. So far I've learned that I need to use @Override onDraw method, but 1. I can't make my parabola discrete and 2. I don't know how to program it so the shape is created step-by-step (with delay).

I also need to draw it after click of a button, so that is another complication for me. Right now I'm trying to draw a simple line step-by-step but this snippet don't work:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        int x1 = 10;
        int x2 = 100;
        int y1 = 10;
        int y2 = 100;
        int diff = x2-x1;

        for (int i = 0; i<diff; i++){
            canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x1+1, y1+1, paint);
            x1++;
            y1++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This feels a bit broad. Is `canvas.drawLine` the method that is drawing your parabola at present? If so, is there a feature in this graphics library to draw with delay? If not, perhaps you need to find a library that will do this for you. If your code is an attempt at doing this, I would suggest removing the third requirement (about button clicks) - your question is more likely to close if you throw in too many help requests. Concentrate on one thing at a time.

Comment: Please make the title of this question reflect its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you some tricks but please finish it your self.

You have to use a timer to refresh your component, if use this, it will refresh "onDraw" each 100ms.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable AlarmRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        invalidate();
    }
};
```

define global variables instead of local.

```
int cc = 0;
int x1 = 10;
int x2 = 100;
int y1 = 10;
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);


    if (cc++ > 100) // STOP HANDLER AFTER COUNTER GETS DONE 
        handler.removeCallbacks(AlarmRunnable);


    System.out.println("CC:" + cc);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(lineWidth);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    for (int i = 0; i<cc; i++){
    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 + 1, y1 + 1, paint);
    x1++;
    y1++;

    }

}
```

start handeler in Constructor

```
 public YOURCOMPONENT(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    handler.post(AlarmRunnable);
 ....
}
```

Comment: I've used Handler to wait for my drawing view to end given task, and it works great.

As for making step-by-step animation - I've created a loop that calculates y-position of object at the end of line, and used it to create a new Path with variable step diistance. I'll post my code later if someone will need it.

Answer (score 0):

**Rendering a Discrete Parabola**

As for drawing a discrete parabola, you should draw points (or circles with a radius size of your choice, but centered at the points) along the different x and y coordinates with a larger step size.

For example, you can draw a parabola from `x=-1` to `x=1` with a step size of 1 by drawing at the following (x, y) points: `(-1, 0), (0, 4), (1, 0)`.

You should make sure that the way you scale your x-axis on your graph, is in a way that there is greater than 1 pixel distance between the points to make it look discrete.

**Animated onDraw**

Regardless of whether your drawing logic within onDraw is correct or not, you are running a long operation with Thread.sleep() on a UI callback, which is bad practice.

Since you are drawing the whole parabola within one call of onDraw, I would assume the whole image is rendered at once rather than animated.

Looking at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620149/how-can-i-draw-an-animated-view-in-android), you should create another thread that is in charge of a rendering loop for your custom view, to create an animation where you draw each frame.